# Get X Y values from Point Geometry or Geography

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking for the MSSQL equivalent of the following mySQL statement:

```
SELECT Y(location) as Lat, X(location) as Lon from myTable;
```

I want to get the X and Y values of my geography I have stored as a geography data type.

I know `STAsText(Location) as Location` will give me the WKT... i just need the X and Y number values.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

For GEOGRAPHY:

```
SELECT location.Lat as Lat, location.Long as Lon from myTable;
```

For GEOMETRY:

```
SELECT location.STY as Lat, location.STX as Lon from myTable;
```

Comment: Do you have a link for a reference for this type of information? If I wanted to know what other properties or methods I could call on location.

Comment: @capdragon: Sure, there you go: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933917(v=sql.105).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933968(v=sql.105).aspx.

Comment: So people don't feel as foolish as me: STY and STX are apparently case-sensitive; sty and stx are not valid and result in "Could not find property or field 'stx' for type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry' in assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types'."

Comment: @Mithrandir does the `ToString()` method return the `LINESTRING()`/`POINT()` part of the call as well? How is it "augmented" with M&Z (as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933803(v=sql.105).aspx) . Is the SRID ever returned? Is the best way to return a string matching the form `(lat, long)` something like '('+CAST(location.lat as varchar(20))+', '+CAST(location.long as varchar(20))+')'