# extract latitude from dbgeography in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a dbgeography column in sql server which stores latitude and longitude information. I want to extract latitude or longitude information using sql query but i couldn't find a way to do so. How could it be done?

No C# code.

Comment: I have tried it in C#, which use the columnname.latitude to find the langitude but i do not know how to use sql server to query it. The information is stored in the following converted format 0xE611111111111111111111111

Comment: i expect it that there is a default way to extract the selecting information as depicted in the following link using sql query but i couldn't figure it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.spatial.dbgeography%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: So does the value **0xE611111111111111111111111** have the information of latitude and longitude? @desmondlee

Comment: yup it contains the value inside but the form is translated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get X Y values from Point Geometry or Geography](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856014/get-x-y-values-from-point-geometry-or-geography)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does something like this work?

```
select Location.Lat, Location.Long from GeographyTable
```

Comment: thanks very much, it works. i use .Latitude and .Longitude previously

Comment: Use STAsText() on Location as a Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography sql